# If i have a login window and want to access another window after i logged in, do i need to use another def into it

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

a beginner here, I was hoping to open a new window after I logged the correct entry by trying to put `import filename.py` but it won't show after the `tm.showinfo`. I don't know what function that will make it happen at the same time it will closed or quit my login window.

I've tried my previous way of doing it to call a command and making a function for it but now I'm totally confused about it,

```
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter.messagebox as tm

class adminlog(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label_username = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_password = Label(self, text="Password")
        self.entry_username = Entry(self)
        self.entry_password = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_username.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.label_password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.logbtn = Button(self, text="Login as Admin", command=self.lg_admin)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.pack()

    def lg_admin(self):
        un = self.entry_username.get()
        ps = self.entry_password.get()
        if un == "admin" and ps == "pito":
            tm.showinfo("Login Info", "Login Successfully")
            import adminpage
        else:
            tm.showerror("Login Error", "Incorrect password or username")

admin = Tk()
a = adminlog(admin)
admin.mainloop()
```

I expect that after I am logged in, then a new window will open after the `tm.showinfo` shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends upon your choice and feel. I will give you two methods and let you decide.

**Disclaimer :** *I prefer the first method.*

---

It is not a good practice to create two `Tk()` windows in the same program. What you can do is have one main window and configure it as and when you want. Here for example, the function `clear_widgets()` clears the login page and shows the next page.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tm

class adminlog(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tk.Label(self, text="Username").grid(row=0, sticky="e")
        tk.Label(self, text="Password").grid(row=1, sticky="e")
        self.entry_username = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_password = tk.Entry(self, show="*")

        self.entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)

        logbtn = tk.Button(self, text="Login as Admin", command=self.lg_admin)
        logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

    def adminpage(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        tk.Label(self, text='Hello Admin !!', bg='brown', fg='white').grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

    def clear_widgets(self):
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

    def lg_admin(self):
        un = self.entry_username.get()
        ps = self.entry_password.get()
        if un == "admin" and ps == "pito":
            tm.showinfo("Login Info", "Login Successfully")
            self.adminpage()
        else:
            tm.showerror("Login Error", "Incorrect password or username")

adminlog().mainloop()
```

[image]

---

If you really want another window and can't do without it, you should use a `Toplevel`. Here is a demonstration.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tm

class adminlog(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tk.Label(self, text="Username").grid(row=0, sticky="e")
        tk.Label(self, text="Password").grid(row=1, sticky="e")
        self.entry_username = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_password = tk.Entry(self, show="*")

        self.entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)

        logbtn = tk.Button(self, text="Login as Admin", command=self.lg_admin)
        logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

    def adminpage(self):
        adp = tk.Toplevel(self)
        tk.Label(adp, text='Hello Admin !!', bg='brown', fg='white').grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

    def lg_admin(self):
        un = self.entry_username.get()
        ps = self.entry_password.get()
        if un == "admin" and ps == "pito":
            tm.showinfo("Login Info", "Login Successfully")
            self.adminpage()
        else:
            tm.showerror("Login Error", "Incorrect password or username")

adminlog().mainloop()
```

[image]

Here you can see, the login window won't go away (if it does, it will take the `Toplevel` with it also). So, I would recommend you to use the first method.

Comment: thanks, it really helps me. the first method is what i'm trying do, because of my half-baked knowledge about tkinter and got easily confused. what i was trying do was on the wrong way so i got stuck everytime. I always overlap tk's in the same program and that's where i am on the wrong path. thanks for the enlightenment.